# how to convert a set of values in tensorflow using tf.case ?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
conversion_dictionary = {1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 4}
converted_vals= [conversion_dictionary[label] for label in labels]
```

It converts the labels from one set of values to another. 
I want to do the same thing using tensors but I know that tesnors are not iterable , so I get the not iterable error for the following code

```
labels = tf.constant([1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1])
conversion_dictionary = {1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 4}
converted_vals = [conversion_dictionary[label] for label in labels]
print(tf.eval(converted_vals))
```

I found the `tf.case` function that might be suitable here but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

So my question is - how to convert between sets of values in tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach which may suit your particular use-case (continuous range of `uint` labels), converting your dictionary into a vector (dict key ➜ vector index):

```python
conversion_vector = [conversion_dictionary[i + 1] for i in range(len(conversion_dictionary))]
conversion_vector = tf.constant(conversion_vector, dtype=tf.int32)

converted_vals = tf.gather(conversion_vector, (labels - 1))
```

(*Note:* `i + 1` and `labels - 1` are to compensate for your labels starting from `1`, not `0`)